# add Image in code instead of xaml in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I want to add image to the grid just like the following xaml file in code(.cs file)

```
<Grid Margin="306,6,6,516">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Height="123" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>
```

I did something like

```
        Grid newGrid = new Grid();
        Thickness thinkness = new Thickness(6,6,306,516);
        newGrid.Margin = thinkness;
        //RowDefinition rowDefin = new RowDefinition();
        //rowDefin.Height = GridLength.Auto;
        //newGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefin);
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Margin = thinkness;
        image.Source = bitmap;
        newGrid.Children.Add(image);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(newGrid);
```

But nothing shows up on the page
Any help?

Comment: Are you adding `Grid` in your `Page`?

Comment: @HarisHasan Yes, I also added `ContentPanel.Children.Add(newGrid)`

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this in code?

Comment: @Xin Because in my app, it allows user to add image to the view, so have to do it without xaml?

Comment: Just one image? Yes, it's definitely doable in xaml. are you using mvvm?

Comment: Then I assume you are using a ListBox control?

Comment: @Xin no, i just set up a grid in root grid and put the image in it. Can a ListBox show the image or just display it's name and info? I'll look it up. Thanks

Comment: If you want the user to add in dynamic number of images, a ListBox is what you need. You can customise the look of it, so yes, it can display images and/or texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newGrid.SetRow(image, 0); 
newGrid.SetColumn(image, 0); 
newGrid.Children.Add(image); 

// Also 

LayoutRoot.Children.Add( newGrid );
```

Comment: and actually newGrid.SetRow and newGrid.SetColumn give me errors

Comment: you didn't define any row or column ?!

Comment: @SamChen Check this links [Grids On The Fly](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/195844.aspx/1) and [Build a Standard UI Dialog Box by Using Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753184.aspx)